# How To Speed Up SQL IN Query With Thousand of Data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, postgresql-14

In my application it needs to get the id of a table in a specific data. The id is not ordered  and is not predictable, so the query uses `IN`. Let's say it has a lot of id's inside like 100.000 ids

The query look like this and it takes approx 10 seconds

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ...
FROM table 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN date1 AND date2 
AND table_id IN (1, ..., 100000)
```

When I `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` this is the return

```
Gather (cost=1002.79..3322893.01 rows=823578 width=24) (actual time=761.500..5453.013 rows=219908 loops=1)

Workers Planned: 2

Workers Launched: 2

Planning Time: 2.433 ms

Execution Time: 5463.276 ms
```

The query look like this and it takes approx 4 seconds

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, ... 
FROM table 
WHERE created_at BETWEEN date1 AND date2 
AND table_id = ANY (
    SELECT value 
    FROM UNNEST(ARRAY([1,...... 100000)]) as value ))
```

here's the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`

```
Nested Loop (cost=14.52..2879232.45 rows=872265 width=24) (actual time=0.485..548.387 rows=219908 loops=1)

Planning Time: 0.938 ms

Execution Time: 558.358 ms
```

I have indexed the `table_id` and `created_at` using `BTREE`

My question is, how to make the query faster ? , is my second query already the most efficient ? and if it's the most efficient, is there any trade off I'm not aware or it has any bug when using `ANY (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(ARRAY[]))` ?

## UPDATED

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS )` First Query

```
QUERY PLAN 
Gather  (cost=1002.79..3324157.83 rows=823891 width=24) (actual time=2059.074..5390.528 rows=219908 loops=1) 
Output: col1, col2, col3 
Workers Planned: 2 
Workers Launched: 2 
Buffers: shared hit=315848 read=522241 dirtied=35 
I/O Timings: read=1103.008 
->  Parallel Seq Scan on table_name  (cost=2.79..3240768.73 rows=343288 width=24) (actual time=2056.255..5363.859 rows=73303 loops=3) 
        Output: col1, col2, col3 
        Filter: (table_id = ANY ('{1,......, 100000}'::integer[])) AND (created_at >= date1::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at <= date2::timestamp with time zone) 
        Rows Removed by Filter: 33444492 
        Buffers: shared hit=315848 read=522241 dirtied=35 
        I/O Timings: read=1103.008 
        Worker 0:  actual time=2054.371..5372.919 rows=69788 loops=1 
        Buffers: shared hit=105747 read=174198 dirtied=3 
        I/O Timings: read=369.176 
        Worker 1:  actual time=2055.867..5369.968 rows=78986 loops=1 
        Buffers: shared hit=105794 read=173495 
        I/O Timings: read=367.726 
Settings: effective_cache_size = '32568248kB', jit = 'off', search_path = 'public' 
Query Identifier: -2771525684851677483 
Planning Time: 1.892 ms 
Execution Time: 5403.505 ms
```

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS )` Second Query

```
QUERY PLAN 
Nested Loop  (cost=14.52..2880414.99 rows=872605 width=24) (actual time=0.432..553.665 rows=219908 loops=1) 
Output: col1, col2, col3 
Buffers: shared hit=392247 dirtied=8 
->  HashAggregate  (cost=13.95..15.95 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=0.407..0.849 rows=1116 loops=1) 
        Output: value.value 
        Group Key: value.value 
        Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 145kB 
        ->  Function Scan on pg_catalog.unnest value  (cost=0.00..11.16 rows=1116 width=4) (actual time=0.071..0.143 rows=1116 loops=1) 
            Output: value.value 
            Function Call: unnest('{1,....,100000}'::integer[]) 
->  Index Scan using table_name_table_id_created_at_idx on table_name  (cost=0.57..14328.73 rows=782 width=16) (actual time=0.047..0.409 rows=197 loops=1116) 
        Output: col1, col2, col3 
        Index Cond: (ss.vehicle_id = value.value) 
        Filter: (created_at >= date1::timestamp with time zone) AND (created_at <= date2::timestamp with time zone) 
        Rows Removed by Filter: 229 
        Buffers: shared hit=392247 dirtied=8 
Settings: effective_cache_size = '32568248kB', jit = 'off', search_path = 'public' 
Query Identifier: 328163023760902820 
Planning Time: 0.374 ms 
Execution Time: 566.648 ms
```

Comment: How about creating an index that contains both columns `(table_id, created_at)` and `(created_at, table_id)`? Keep the one that is PG chooses to use (the latter one most probably).

Comment: Hi - which of those 2 queries are you asking people to comment on? What’s your single question that you are asking? Also, those 2 queries are not semantically the same

Comment: `Let's say` on the contrary, specify the exact situation. 100K rows is *not* a lot of data, especially if the columns are indexed. You can't pass 100K ids in an `IN` clause though. The second query is completely different but still slow because no index can be applied to that array

Comment: Where do the IDs come from? Some ETL or batch job? The fast way would be to store them in a staging table with proper indexes and write a normal INNER JOIN or `ID IN` query

Comment: @NickW The first query is my initial query, the second one is what I've tried. I want to know if there are any query that is faster than the second one, or if it is the most efficient, does it has any flaw or bug in the future

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's coming from batch job

Comment: @SalmanA it has been indexed like this `table_name_table_id_created_at_idx`

Comment: @MichaelHalim try an index with opposite order. created_at is searched using between clause while table_id list can have gaps so created_at, table_id - in theory - should be better.

Comment: What is coming from a batch job? What data, in what form? How is it converted to that long list of IDs? A script with 100K IDs takes *more* space than a table with 100K rows and can't use indexes on the values. Why not COPY the data into a temporary table and do a JOIN ?

Comment: Could you please share the complete DDL for the tables and indexes involved? And the complete result from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for your SQL statements? (all in plain text, as an update of your question)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried temporary tables, it takes longer than the first query

Comment: @MichaelHalim as the two queries are semantically different and return different results, it’s still not clear to me why you’ve included the second query? It’s not a faster version of the first query

Comment: @nick why is second query different? how can it produce different results? `= any` is same as `in`

Comment: Could you also include the DDL for the table and indexes involved? It looks like there is something wrong with the indexes, but without the DDL it's impossible to see what is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHalim did you index the ID column in the staging table? You're asking people to guess. In any case the detailed execution plan shows that PostgreSQL actually creates a Hash index on the fly before it starts using an index scan instead of an index seek in a loop. How many actual values are there in `(ARRAY([...` ? The numbers are nowhere near 100K

Comment: @SalmanA this isn't `IN (SELECT ID from somewhere)` but `IN (const_id_1,......)`. The row counts in the second execution plan are nowhere near 100K IDs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the query I'm executing is about 2000+ ids, but in production the number can be as high as 100k ids but I have no access in the production db

Comment: @MichaelHalim There's a huge difference between 1-2K values and 100K values. The execution plans will be completely different. In this case the database created a hash index on the fly because it knew there were only 1K values which took only 145KB RAM. It won't do the same for 100K values.

Comment: @MichaelHalim which PostgreSQL version are you using? It's surprising that the database didn't create an index for the first query as well. For whatever reason the database decided that would be too expensive in the first case.

Comment: random_page_cost is most likely too high, the default is 4. Check lower values, closer to 1.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos version 14.10

Answer (score 0):

Create test data:

```
CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE foo( id INT NOT NULL, created_at INT NOT NULL, data INT NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO foo SELECT n, random()*10000000, n FROM generate_series(1,40000000) n;
CREATE INDEX ON foo(id);
CREATE INDEX ON foo(created_at);
VACUUM ANALYZE foo;
```

Due to the large number of ids's in the query I'll use python:

```
ids = [ n*100 for n in range(100000) ]
cursor.execute( """
    EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM foo 
    WHERE id =ANY(%s) AND created_at BETWEEN 1000000 AND 3000000
    """, (ids,) )
for row in cursor:
    print(row[0][:200])

Index Scan using foo_id_idx on foo  (cost=0.56..334046.00 rows=20121 width=12) (actual time=8.092..331.779 rows=19845 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800,1900,2000,2100,2200,2300,2400,2500,2600,2700,2800,2900,3000,3100,3200,3300,3400,3500,3600,
  Filter: ((created_at >= 1000000) AND (created_at <= 3000000))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 80154
Planning Time: 39.578 ms
Execution Time: 358.758 ms
```

Planning is slow, due to the large array.

It is using the index on id to fetch rows, then filters them based on created_at. Thus rows not satisfying the condition on created_at still require heap fetches. Including created_at in the index would be useful.

An index on (created_at,id) would allow to scan the requested range of created_at, but it cannot index on ids. So the ids would have to be pulled out of the index and filtered. This would only be useful if the condition on created_at is very narrow and the most selctive in the query. Looking at the row counts in your EXPLAIN, I don't feel this is the case.

An index with id as the first column allows to fetch rows for each id directly. Then created_at has to be compared with the requested range. I feel this is more useful.

```
CREATE INDEX ON foo( id ) INCLUDE ( created_at );

Index Scan using foo_id_created_at_idx on foo  (cost=0.56..334046.00 rows=20121 width=12) (actual time=3.955..278.250 rows=19845 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (id = ANY ('{0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800,1900,2000,2100,2200,2300,2400,2500,2600,2700,2800,2900,3000,3100,3200,3300,3400,3500,3600,
  Filter: ((created_at >= 1000000) AND (created_at <= 3000000))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 80154
Planning Time: 37.395 ms
Execution Time: 299.370 ms
```

This pulls created_at from the index, avoiding heap fetches for rows that will be rejected, so it is slightly faster.

```
CREATE INDEX ON foo( id, created_at );
```

This would be useful if there were many rows for each id, each having a different created_at value, which is not the case here.

This query may cause lots of random IOs, so if the table is on spinning disk and not SSD, it will take a lot longer.

Using IN() instead of =ANY() does not change anything.

Besides including created_at in the index to avoid extra IO, there's not much opportunity to make it faster. This will need one index scan per id, there are 100k, so it comes down to 3µs per id which is pretty fast. Transferring that many rows to the client will also take time.

If you really need it faster, I'd recommend splitting the batches of id's into smaller chunks, and executing it in parallel over several connections. This has the advantage of parallelizing data encoding and decoding, and also processing on the client.

The following parallel python code runs in 100ms, which is quite a bit faster.

```
db = None
def query( ids ):
    if not ids: return
    global db
    if not db:
        db = psycopg2.connect("user= password=  dbname=test")
        db.cursor().execute( "PREPARE myplan AS SELECT * FROM unnest($1::INTEGER[]) get_id JOIN foo ON (foo.id=get_id AND foo.created_at BETWEEN $2 AND $3)")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute( "EXECUTE myplan(%s,1000000,3000000)", (ids,) )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ids = [ n*100 for n in range(100000) ]
    chunks = [ids[offset:(offset+1000)] for offset in range( 0, len(ids)+1, 1000 )]
    st = time.time()
    with Pool(10) as p:
        p.map(query, chunks)
    print( time.time()-st )
```